# Updating MySQL with a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I'm trying to update a field where username = $username

```
UPDATE userinfo SET password = $newpass WHERE username = $username
```

However, I'm getting the error "#1054 - Unknown column 'bob' in 'where clause'" when I replace `$username` with `bob`.

Any idea how to correctly write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha! After your comment, it's clear that you're not wrapping text in quotes:

```
UPDATE userinfo SET password = $newpass WHERE username = '$username'
```

Since `$username` is a text value, you need to put single quotes around it so that SQL parses it as text, not as a column.

Comment: getting this error "#1054 - Unknown column 'bob' in 'where clause'" When i replace $username with bob

Comment: try replacing it with 'bob' (with the quotes)

Comment: Works great now, thanks! Its generous people like yourself that help people learn and for that i am very appreciative.

Comment: Glad to help, and glad you got it fixed!